# How to use statistics to speed up row-wise computations on a data.frame?

Tags: r, model-evaluation, computational-statistics, function

I have a data frame with 10,000 rows and 40 columns. I am trying to apply a function to each of these rows. For each row, I am expecting to return a scalar which is the value of the statistic I am calculating in this function. Below is what I have done so far;

```
library(sandwich)

# Creating example data #

nrows=10000
ncols=40
n1=20
n2=20
df=data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# Function to evaluate on each row of df #

get_est= function(x){
mod = lm(x~cov$group)
vcov = vcovHC(mod)
coef = as.numeric(mod$coefficients[2])
se = sqrt(as.numeric(diag(vcov)[2]))
stats = coef/se
return(stats)
}

# Applying above function to full data #

t1=Sys.time()
estimates=apply(df, 1, function(x) get_est(x))
t2=Sys.time()-t1

# Time taken by apply function

Time difference of 32.10623 secs
```

Is there a way to significantly decrease the time taken to implement get_est() on the full data? The main reason I need to speed up the computation on a single df is because I have 1000 more data frames with the same dimension and I have to apply this function to each row to each of these data frames simultaneously. To illustrate, below is the broader situation I am dealing with;

```
# Creating example data

set.seed(1234)
nrows = 10000
ncols = 40
n1 = 20
n2 = 20
df.list = list()
for(i in 1:1000){
  df.list[[i]] = data.frame(t(replicate(nrows, rnorm(ncols, 100, 3))))
}

# Applying get_est() to each row and to each of data frame in df.list #

all.est = foreach(j = 1:length(df.list), .combine = cbind, .packages = 'sandwich') %dopar% {
  cov=data.frame(group=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))
  est = apply(df.list[[j]], 1, function(x) get_est(x))
  return(est)
}
```

Even after parallelizing it is taking hours to finish. My ultimate objective is to significantly cut down the time to obtain "all.est" which will contain 10000 rows and 1000 columns where each column has the stats estimates for the respective data set. Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: More suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, posted there too!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for an explicit request not to cross-post on SE.

Comment: The answer below about precomputing parts of the results relies on details of the algorithm and requires statistical expertise to derive. Compare this to the answer on SE about parallelizing, which does not and offers relatively little performance improvement, and it is very clear that this question is best answered here. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support @ChrisHaug!! @Nick Cox Thanks for letting me know the guidelines I will definitely keep this in mind before posting anything in future.

Comment: Hi @Capri, I see that you've made an edit to your post which invalidates the answer. This is very harmful to the site! Invalidating an answer means that the people who have spent time and effort to understand and answer your question have their work negated. When you realize that your question is not exactly what you wanted to know, you should instead **ask a new question** which is clear and specific to your problem. I'm going to roll back your edit so that your question is stated in its original form, and Ben's answer is responsive. Please post a new question about `rlm`.